# AD query - get bitlocker active computers

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have query in Active Directory which should return all computers with bitlocker not active based on this script:

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1083065-bitlocker-status-on-all-computers

Script works fine so the values are there.

But my query is not returning anything.
It looks like this:

```
(&(&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=msFVE-RecoveryInformation)(!(msFVE-RecoveryPassword=*))))
```

I want to return computers which dont have active bitlocker.

Can someone point me to right direction where could be mistake, still learning with ldap queries.

//EDIT

So i found out msFVE-RecoveryInformation is object by it self, when i do:

```
(&(&(objectClass=msFVE-RecoveryInformation)(msFVE-RecoveryPassword=*)))
```

It filters objects with recovery keys but name of computers is coded in atribute "distinguishedName like this:

```
CN=2020-02-10T16:32:51\+01:00{4C74584A-BF6C-4AFA-9E46-582DDFC207A6},CN=NAMEOFNTB,OU=computers,OU=blabla,DC=test,DC=local
```

Somehow i can filter only computers with this attribute?